# What is the best way to guarantee this type of SSH connection?

Tags: linux, ssh, reverse-proxy, ssh-keys, ssh-tunnel

I have this script that creates this "reverse" SSH connection from machine A to machine B, so that I can access machine A from machine.

**How I did it**

This is the script machine A uses to connect to machine B, which runs at startup once:

```
spawn ssh -fN -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa -R 20007:localhost:22 machine_b@123.456.789.012
expect "*passphrase*"
send "the passphrase string\r"
expect eof
```

Then on the machine B, I only have to connect to machine A like this:

`ssh pi@localhost -p 20007`

Why the hell I am using this "reverse" SSH connection? Well, this is the only way machine B can see and connect to machine A, because machine A is behind a NAT and it cannot be addressed, so the connection must come from machine A.

**The problem**

This works fine, despite the fact it is all hardcoded, specially the passphrase part. However it has an issue... If machine A's Internet goes poo poo, the SSH connection closes and does not re-open when the Internet comes up.

**The solution attempt**

My first solution was to have a cronjob running the SSH script every hour, but soon I had 24 simultaneous SSH connections per day from machine A to machine B, and by the end of the week machine B died from excess SSH connections.

**The Question**

So, is there any other way to make machine A "regenerate" the connection only when it gets disconnected, and make sure that the old connection is killed so that I have one and only one SSH connection from machine A to B?

Thanks!

Comment: How to reliably keep an SSH tunnel open?
 https://superuser.com/questions/37738/how-to-reliably-keep-an-ssh-tunnel-open

Comment: If for some reason you still want to use your code, you could have a script called by your cron job which checks for active connections on the specific port you use. For that, losf -i :port_number will give your the PID, if any, of processes using port_number.

Comment: Oh and by the way, if you have access to the NAT configuration you could use port forwarding : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Answer (score 0):

You could just check the current connections using a netstat, grep for port 22 and if it's established do nothing. i.e netstat -an | egrep 22